# Map array of objects based on Id

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, array.prototype.map

Noob javascript enthusiast here.

I'm trying to understand the various higher-order functions of javascript, and am particularly curious with the possibilities of .map() on an array of objects.

Suppose you have the following:

```
selectedId = ['u1', 'u2']
data = [
{id: 'u1', color: 'red', age: '24'},
{id: 'u2', color: 'blue', age: '18'},
{id: 'u3', color: 'yellow', age: '15'}
]
```

How would you go about creating a new array that only contains the object of u1 and u2? I.e:

```
selectedData = [
{id: 'u1', color: 'red', age: '24'},
{id: 'u2', color: 'blue', age: '18'},
]
```

Comment: from which array depends the order of the result? have you tried anything? what does not work?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to `Array#map` over your `selectedId` array, then find corresponding object inside `data` array using `Array#find`.

```js
const selectedId = ['u1', 'u2'];

const data = [
  {id: 'u1', color: 'red', age: '24'},
  {id: 'u2', color: 'blue', age: '18'},
  {id: 'u3', color: 'yellow', age: '15'}
];

const res = selectedId.map((id) => data.find((o) => o.id === id));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, You can use array filter like

```
data.filter(el => selectedId.includes(el.id));
```

would give

```
[
{id: 'u1', color: 'red', age: '24'},
{id: 'u2', color: 'blue', age: '18'}
]
```

Or alternatively

```
selectedId.map((id) => data.find((el) => el.id === id));
```

would give

```
[
{id: 'u1', color: 'red', age: '24'},
{id: 'u2', color: 'blue', age: '18'}
]
```